# Pagination next_posts_link() and previous_posts_link() not working on wordpress custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to display next and previous page on my wordpress's custom post type. But the links are not generating. What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $video = array('post_type' => 'e_tv', 'posts_per_page' => 1,'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged);
    $tv_query = new WP_Query($video);
    while ($tv_query->have_posts()) : $tv_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <!--video1-->
    <section class="e_tv">
        <h4><?php the_title()?></h4>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </section>
    <!--/video1-->



        <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
    <div class="e_sep"></div>

    <section class="e_nxtprev">
        <div class="e_next"><?php previous_posts_link('%link', 'PREVIOUS PAGE', $tv_query->max_num_pages) ?></div>
        <div class="e_prev"><?php next_posts_link('%link', 'NEXT PAGE', $tv_query->max_num_pages) ?></div>
    </section>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found my mistake myself... So sharing it in detail for future reference:

I have been using the `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` functions with wrong parameters for the whole time now and no one even notices this.

`next_posts_link()` supports two parameters which is: `$label` and `$max_pages` and `previous_posts_link()` only support one parameter which is: `$label` and you can see I have used three parameters instead, which is the main reason for these functions to malfunction.

So the correct code is:

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $video = array('post_type' => 'e_tv', 'posts_per_page' => 1,'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged);
    $tv_query = new WP_Query($video);
    while ($tv_query->have_posts()) : $tv_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <!--video1-->
    <section class="e_tv">
        <h4><?php the_title()?></h4>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </section>
    <!--/video1-->



        <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
    <div class="e_sep"></div>

    <section class="e_nxtprev">
        <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
        <div class="e_next"><?php previous_posts_link('PREVIOUS PAGE') ?></div>
        <div class="e_prev"><?php next_posts_link('NEXT PAGE', $tv_query->max_num_pages) ?></div>
    </section>
```

References: [next_posts_link()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link), [previous_posts_link()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link)

Hope this will help to guys like me in future...

Answer (score 1):

you may have a look at the old discussion from the below url,

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-with-custom-post-type-listing

especially look for the answer given by `rafaelxy` & `bigevilbrain`

Comment: i don't know they are expert or not but they figured out that time how to solve this issue

Comment: Yeah like 6 years ago... I'm checking on it... lets see!

Comment: Ok Have checked it ... `rafaelxy` saying that post type name and page name should not be same. But this is not my case ... My page and post type name are way different. The links are just not showing up... any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

use 'page' instead of 'paged' if the query is on a static front page, like

```
  $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
  $video = array('post_type' => 'e_tv', 'posts_per_page' => 1,'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged);
```

And try using

```
 <?php

 echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $tv_query->max_num_pages );
 echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
 ?>
```

Comment: Making it `page` instead of `paged didn't work for me... 